# Using acf frontend admin for register new user

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i use the acf frontend admnin, i have create a form for register new user in the frontend of my site, i have create a field, the type is select field, the name is country, and i need the choices to be the countries from the user profile of wordpress. i use the below code but it is not working.

```
 // Add choices from "Country" field in user profile to "Select" field in ACF frontend 
 form for new user
 function add_country_choices_to_select_field($field) {
 // Check if this is the "Select" field you want to modify
 if ($field['key'] == 'country') {
    // Get "Country" field choices for first user in WordPress
    $users = get_users();
    $user = $users[0];
    $country_choices = get_field('billing_country', 'user_' . $user->ID);
    // Add each choice as an option to the "Select" field
    if (!empty($country_choices)) {
        foreach ($country_choices as $value => $label) {
            $field['choices'][$value] = $label;
         }
     }
  }
  return $field;
 }
 add_filter('acf/load_field/key=country', 'add_country_choices_to_select_field');
```

in the choices of the field in the plugin i haven't insert anything.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an issue in which it only retrieves the country choices for the first user in WordPress, instead of the current user who is attempting to register.

Use `get_current_user_id()` to get the current user id who is registering.

```
function add_country_choices_to_select_field($field) {
    // Check if this is the "Select" field you want to modify
    if ($field['name'] == 'country') {
    
        // get_current_user_id() instead get_users()
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $country_choices = get_field('billing_country', 'user_' . $user_id);
        if (!empty($country_choices)) {
            foreach ($country_choices as $value => $label) {
                $field['choices'][$value] = $label;
            }
        }
    }
    return $field;
}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=country', 'add_country_choices_to_select_field');
```

Comment: @Skoyntoyflis you are trying to get the value of an acf field for a user who has just registered and does not have the billing_country meta-data or the data is not an array. So you get an error

Comment: Thank you! althougth i receive that message "valid argument supplied for foreach()". Also is there any change of being all the code wrong? because the countries that i want to get in the choices of the field are not coming from a acf field but i need them from the default field of the user profile of wordpress site. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Skoyntoyflis at what point and how do you set the billing_country field?

Comment: I use a form in the frontend for register a new user, the form adds almost all the fields( first and last name, password, company, company address, post code etc.) the default fields of a wordpress user, but i need also to choose the country. billing_country is the meta key of the country/region field of the user in wordpress. i hope to make you understand what i am trying to do. thank you.